# spring boot application startup failed with two datasources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, datasource

I am using two different `datasources` for `MySQL` in my Spring Boot application. The container fails to start up with the error below. I also tried to switch one of the datasource to be H2. I still get same error.

entire source code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/SpringDevSeattle/multiple-datasource/src)

**src/main/java/application.properties**

```
#datasource
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_table
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


##secondary Datasource
#spring.sec.datasource.username=test
#spring.sec.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comp_table
#spring.sec.datasource.password=test
#spring.sec.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#secondary Datasource
spring.sec.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.sec.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.sec.datasource.username=sa
spring.sec.datasource.password=
spring.sec.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**src/main/java/com/company/foo/config/DBConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {


    @Bean(name="priDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource priDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "secDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.sec.datasource")
    public DataSource secDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcPriTemplate")
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcPriTemplate(@Qualifier("priDataSource") DataSource hostds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(hostds);
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcSecTemplate")
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcSecTemplate(@Qualifier("secDataSource") DataSource secDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secDataSource);
    }

}
```

**src/main/java/com/company/foo/Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
2016-08-16 15:37:28.186  WARN 22600 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
2016-08-16 15:37:28.192  INFO 22600 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-08-16 15:37:28.212  INFO 22600 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-08-16 15:37:28.240 ERROR 22600 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at com.company.foo.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [sample-proj-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [sample-proj-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [sample-proj-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [sample-proj-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:603) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:443) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:424) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:600) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you sure your properties file is located at the appropriate place? Should be at the root

Comment: yes. sure. I have linked the github repo above, if you want to have a look at it

Comment: Yes I sow your link but can't access with my android.  Will check with pc.

Comment: The repo link isn't entered correctly. The link is just going to an `about:blank` page.

Comment: @ShawnClark: I edited now. it should be active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it is having trouble making the `EntityManagerFactory` but you don't explicitly create on for each of your datasources. If you check out the Spring Data example for multiple datasources you can see how they outline creating the different datasources.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Once I removed spring data from dependencies, app started without any errors.